# Java: Logger.addHandler is undefined

Tags: java, logging, output, undefined-symbol

Like the title says, the `addHandler(Handler handler)` void for the `Logger` class appears to be undefined in my script.

For context, I am running the program on IntelliJ IDEA. I am trying to use the `addHandler` command in order to specify a file destination for the output log file that the `Logger` class writes to.

I've been told that the output log file should be in the `Sun\Java\Deployment\log` directory but the folder is completely empty.

In all honesty, I could really care less where the log file is written to. But, seeing as it's not in the folder it's supposed to be in, I thought specifying a different destination would do the trick.

This problem also seems to occur with other voids such as `getHandlers()` so the issue might be more serious than I imagined.

A snippet of my code:

```java
import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;

public class Main {
     private final static Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Main.class.getName());

     public static void main(String... args){
        FileHandler fileHandler;

        try {
            fileHandler = new FileHandler("log.txt");
            SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
            LOGGER.addHandler(fileHandler); // error
            fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
        } catch (SecurityException | IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}
```

And when I run the program, the build error that follows:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method addHandler(java.util.logging.FileHandler)
  location: variable LOGGER of type org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger
```

Maven dependency setup

```xml
<dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.17.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
```

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check imports of logger.
Java.util.logging.* provides addHandler(). [Check this article for more information](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/logger-addhandler-method-in-java-with-examples/amp/)